# Xls substring string-length starts-with

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm quite new to xsl and only need this part to be finished with a project. So instead of doing a lot of testing and failing, I guess someone can solve this quite easy. I know progamming in other languages so I guess this to be an easy case for some?

So here's the problem. 
I have template that looks something like this:

```
<xsl:template name ="TemplateName1">
<xsl:param name ="ParmId1"/>
<cbc:Element1>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$ParmId1= 'N15'">Net per 15 days</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="$ParmId1= '15'">Net per 15 days</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</cbc:Element1>
</xsl:template>
```

What I want is a more dynamic approch. I know the parameter will start with a letter then numbers, or it will be just numbers. It will only be 1-2 digits in the number. I want the result to be like:
"Net per 'parameter' days"

If only the parameter doesn't start with a letter, then I need to change the $ParmId1 to remove the first char.

*Update:
The first letter will always be the letter 'N' - So examples: 4, N4, 30, N30.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your input as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Result>N30</Result>
</root>
```

An **XSLT 1.0** solution to achieve what you have specified can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:call-template name="TemplateName1">
        <xsl:with-param name="ParmId1" select="Result"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name ="TemplateName1">
    <xsl:param name ="ParmId1"/>
      <cbc:Element1>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with($ParmId1, 'N')">Net per <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($ParmId1,'N')" /> days</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>Net per <xsl:value-of select="$ParmId1" /> days</xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </cbc:Element1>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltransform.net/eieE3Q1

Answer (score 1):

If your parameter match the expression `^N?[1234567890]+$` you could use the [`translate`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate) XPath function:

```
translate($ParmId1,'N','')
```

This simple removes any posible appearance of `N` character from the string. More complex solutions are available in newer versions of XPath/XSLT